# Grails integration test response object not changing after subsequent calls to controllers

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing

I have the following integration test.  Essentially it saves an "account" object in our db that has a limit of 3 SdkApplication objects in the 1:many relationship.  I want to test that this is enforced correctly in the controller by running an integration test.  The only problem is that the last line of sac.response.json is returning the same thing each time even though different results have been rendered by the controller.

Is there some response clear method that needs to be called in between invocations of a grails controller in an integration test?

```
void testAddTooManySdkApplicationBackOfficeUserFails() {
    doTestLoginJasonBackofficeUser(sac)
    def account = ObjectMother.account("TestCo")
    account.maxAuthorized3rdPartyApps = 3
    account.company.save(flush: true)
    account.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    3.times {
        setJSONRequest([name: "Amazing Application", accountId: account.id], sac)
        sac.addSdkApplication()
        assertSDKAddedCorrectly(sac.response.json as JSONObject)
    }

    setJSONRequest([name: "Amazing Application", accountId: account.id], sac)
    sac.addSdkApplication()
    def resp = sac.response.json as JSONObject
    assertFalse("Should have failed to add an SDKApplication as the limit was reached", resp.success)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try calling yourController.reset() or response.reset()

Comment: `controller.reset()` resulted in a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` error for me, but `response.reset()` worked great.